# Attach bootstrap row underneath the row above it no matter the size of the first row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 rows in my footer, the first row has a dynamically updating length of columns. The bottom row is mostly static, small width footer row.

When the first row changes its height because more items were added or something, white space appears between the 2 rows.

[image: first row]

[image]

As you can see, when items are added white space appears.

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="footerColumns">
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $getColumns; $i++) {

    ?>
    <div class="col-md-<?php echo $columns; ?>">
        <h2><?php echo $headerColumn[$i]; ?></h2>
        <?php for ($y = 0; $y < 5; $y++) {
            ?><p>hi</p><?php
        } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
} 
?>
</div>

<div class="row" id="bottomFooter">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>hi</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>hi</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer-container
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: #252629;
color: white;
}

#footerColumns
{
padding: 25px 50px 0 50px;
}

#bottomFooter
{
margin-top: 158px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
position: relative;
height: 50px;
bottom: 0;
}
```

I also have it set as a sticky footer so I have css like:

```
html
{
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}

body
{
margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#bottomFooter
{
margin-top: auto;
background-color: black;
color: white;
position: relative;
height: 50px;
bottom: 0;
}
```

It brings both the rows closer and will remove the white space as well. The white space was coming due to high margin-top value. I have used auto to keep it simple. you can change it with some smaller value (<10px) if you wish too.

Comment: that was so simple and it worked! totally should have figured that out myself